# C# Nested Loop not repeating entirely

Tags: nested-loops

There is an error somewhere in my nested loops causing the program to not display the prime factorizations of the value when the program increases the value by 1. Does anyone have any ideas what I did wrong? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace Primes
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int minValue = 15,
            maxValue = 21;
        int x = minValue,
            y = 2;

        WriteLine("Prime Factors:");
        WriteLine();

        for (minValue = x; minValue <= maxValue; minValue++)
        {
            Write("\n\t{0}", minValue);
            if(minValue <= maxValue)
                while (x > 2)
                {
                    if (x % y == 0)
                    {
                        Write(" : " + Convert.ToString(y));
                        x = x / y;
                    }
                    else
                        ++y;
            }
        }
        ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Learn hot to use a debugger, and step through code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...this is more precise and closer to what you are looking for I believe...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using static System.Console;

namespace Primes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int minValue = 15,
                maxValue = 21;


            WriteLine("Prime Factors:");
            WriteLine();

            while (minValue <= maxValue )
            {

                int x = minValue;
                int y = 2;

                Write("\n\t{0}", minValue);

                if (minValue <= maxValue)
                    while (x >= 2)
                    {
                        if (x % y == 0)
                        {
                            Write(" : " + Convert.ToString(y));
                            x = x / y;
                        }
                        else
                            ++y;
                    }
                minValue++;
            }
            ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```